# Porque solo se muestra el ID y no la información de la tabla en mi index.php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Actualmente estoy haciendo que en mis productos aparezca su estado "disponible" o "agotado" cree una nueva tabla llamada "estado" en mi base de datos... En mi tabla de productos agregue una nueva columna llamada "estado_id" donde se almacena en que estado se encuentra el producto.

Base de datos:

**estado:**

[image]

**productos**

[image: 2]

Entonces al colocarlo para que se muestre en el listado de mis productos en index.php aparece es solamente el ID de la tabla estado. Por ejemplo en la imagen de abajo dice "1" y necesito que aparezca el estado del producto, que diga si se encuentra disponible o agotado.

[image: IMAGEN 1]

index.php

```
    <div class="productos">
        <a href="productos/producto.php?id=<?php echo $productos['id']?>">
  <img src="<?php echo '/images/' . $productos['image']; ?>" class="img-test">
  <p class="text-test"><?php echo $productos['title']?></p>
            

            <p class="status"><?php echo $productos['tipo_id']; ?></p>
 
            
            
        </a>
</div>
```

productos.php

```
<?php 

include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/app/database/db.php');
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/app/helpers/validatePost.php');

$table = 'productos';
$categorias = selectAll('categorias');
$estado = selectAll('estado');

$errors = array();
$id = '';
$title = '';
$body = '';
$estadoid = '';
$topic_id = '';

$productos = selectAll($table);


if (isset($_POST['add-post'])) {
    $_POST['topic_id']=serialize($_POST['topic_id']);
    $errors = validatePost($_POST);
    
    if (!empty($_FILES['image']['name'])) {
        $image_name = time() . '_' . $_FILES['image']['name'];
        $destination = "../../images/" . $image_name;
        
        $result = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $destination);
        
        if ($result){
            $_POST['image'] = $image_name;
        } else {
            array_push($errors, "¡Algo fallo al subir la imagen!");
        }
        
        
    } else {
      array_push($errors, "¡Necesitas subir una imagen!");
    }
    
    if (count($errors) === 0){
        unset($_POST['add-post']);
        $post_id = create($table, $_POST);
        $_SESSION['message'] = '¡Post creado correctamente!';
        $_SESSION['type'] = 'success';
        header('location: ../../admin/posts/index.php');
        exit();
    } else {
        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $body = $_POST['body'];
        $topic = $_POST['topic_id'];
        $estadoid = $_POST['estado_id'];
    }
}

if (isset($_GET['id'])){
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $post = selectOne($table, ['id' => $id]);
}

if (isset($_GET['del_id'])){
    $id = $_GET['del_id'];    
    $count = delete($table, $id);
    $_SESSION['message'] = '¡Post eliminado correctamente!';
    $_SESSION['type'] = 'success';
    header('location: ../../admin/posts/index.php');
    exit();
}

if (isset($_POST['update-post'])){
    $_POST['topic_id']=serialize(array_values($_POST['topic_id']));
    $_POST['estado_id']=serialize($_POST['estado_id']);
    $errors = validateEdit($_POST); 
    
    if (count($errors) === 0){
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        unset($_POST['update-post'], $_POST['id']);
        $post_id = update($table, $id, $_POST);
        $_SESSION['message'] = '¡Post actualizado correctamente!';
        $_SESSION['type'] = 'success';
        header('location: ../../admin/topics/index.php');
        exit();        
    } else {
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $body = $_POST['body'];
        $topic = $_POST['topic_id'];
        $estadoid = $_POST['estado_id'];
}
} 
?>
```

db.php

```
<?php

session_start();
require('connect.php');

function dd($value)
{
    echo "<pre>", print_r($value, true), "</pre>";
    die();
}


function executeQuery($sql, $data)
{
    global $conn;
    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $values = array_values($data);
    $types = str_repeat('s', count($values));
    $stmt->bind_param($types, ...$values);
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt;
}


function selectAll($table, $conditions = [])
{
    global $conn;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table";
    if (empty($conditions)) {
        $sql = $sql . " ORDER BY id DESC";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $records = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        return $records;    
    } else {
        // $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE username='ElVictox' AND admin=1";
        
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($conditions as $key => $value) {
            if ($i === 0){
                $sql = $sql . " WHERE $key=?";
                
            } else {
                $sql = $sql . " AND $key=?"; 
            }
            $i++;
        }
        
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $values = array_values($conditions);
        $types = str_repeat('s', count($values));
        $stmt->bind_param($types, $values);
        $stmt->execute();
        $records = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        return $records;
    }
}



function selectOne($table, $conditions)
{
    global $conn;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table ";

        $i = 0;
                foreach ($conditions as $key => $value) {
            if ($i === 0){
                $sql = $sql . " WHERE $key=?";
                
            } else {
               $sql = $sql . " AND $key=?"; 
            }
            $i++;
        }
        $sql = $sql . " LIMIT 1";
        $stmt = executeQuery($sql, $conditions);
        $records = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
        return $records;
    }

function create($table, $data)
{
    global $conn;
    $sql = "INSERT INTO $table SET ";
      
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            if ($i === 0){
                $sql = $sql . " $key=?";
                
            } else {
                $sql = $sql . ", $key=?"; 
            }
            $i++;
        }
    $stmt = executeQuery($sql, $data);
    $id = $stmt->insert_id;
    return $id;
    
}

function update($table, $id, $data)
{
    global $conn;
    $sql = "UPDATE $table SET ";
      
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            if ($i === 0){
                $sql = $sql . " $key=?";
                
            } else {
                $sql = $sql . ", $key=?"; 
            }
            $i++;
        }
    
    $sql = $sql . " WHERE id=?";
    $data['id'] = $id;
    $stmt = executeQuery($sql, $data);
    return $stmt->affected_rows;
    
}


function delete($table, $id)
{
    global $conn;
    $sql = "DELETE FROM $table WHERE id=?";
      
    $stmt = executeQuery($sql, ['id' => $id]);
    return $stmt->affected_rows;
    
}
```

Comment: Ese `1` es el valor de la columna `estado_id`. En ningún momento haces un JOIN con la tabla `estado` para obtener el valor de la columna `name`. Para este caso, dado que son solo dos valores, podrías resolverlo in situ con un ternario, pero para otros casos debes saber que en este tipo de escenarios debes hacer un JOIN con la otra tabla en tu instrucción SQL.

Comment: @A.Cedano y como realizo ese ternario o mediante JOIN?

Comment: Intento descifrar tu código pero está un poquito complicado y poco claro. Allí donde recibes el dato puedes hacer algo así: `$mEstado=($elValor == 1) ? "DISPONIBLE" : "AGOTADO";`  (aquí `$elValor` sería el dato donde recibes el valor `1`  o `2` de la columna) y luego muestras el valor de `$mEstado`. En cuanto a hacer con `JOIN` no podría decirte en este contexto, porque estás usando métodos genéricos para hacer  `SELECT` de cualquier tabla, meter un `JOIN` ahí lo veo complicado, es probable que para eso tengas que crear un nuevo método para consultas con `JOIN`.

Comment: @A.Cedano En donde debo colocar eso?, ya lo intente pero me sigue lanzando la ID en el index.php

Comment: No sé si sea esta parte del código: `<p class="status"><?php echo $productos['tipo_id']; ?></p>`, intenta así: **`<p class="status"><?php echo $productos['tipo_id']==1 ? "DISPONIBLE" : "AGOTADO"; ?></p>`**

Comment: @A.Cedano MUCHISIMAS GRACIAS!!, me funciono correctamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estás mostrando el valor numérico, aquí:

```
<p class="status"><?php echo $productos['tipo_id']; ?></p>
```

Para obtener el valor de `DISPONIBLE` o `AGOTADO` tendrías que hacer una consulta SQL donde unas mediante `JOIN` las tablas `productos`, y `estado`. Pero en el contexto actual esto es difícilmente aplicable, porque usas un método generíco para todas las consultas. Para hacerlo mediante `JOIN` tendrías que crear otro tipo de método, con lógica que implemente `JOIN`, algo parecido a lo que hacen los ORMs.

Dado que en este caso se trata sólo de dos valores, puedes usar un ternario para asignar `DISPONIBLE` o `AGOTADO` según el valor que haya, algo así:

```
<p class="status"><?php echo $productos['tipo_id']==1 ? "DISPONIBLE" : "AGOTADO"; ?></p>
```

Ahí, se imprimirá `DISPONIBLE` cuando el valor sea igual a `1`, de lo contrario se imprimirá `AGOTADO`.

### Nota sobre codificación estricta

Aún queda un aspecto por cubrir. ¿Qué pasa si no es ni `1` ni `2`? Deberías asegurarte, donde se generan los datos, que ese valor venga con `1` o con `2`, o de lo contrario que sea `NULL` y evaluar aquí en primer lugar la no nulidad del dato, asignando un valor por defecto y luego hacer la evaluación con el ternario. Dejo esta nota para invitarte a escribir un código estricto, que controle el estado de los datos (si son nulos, si están vacíos, etc).

Comment: Disculpa y si en tal caso agrego un nuevo dato a la tabla estado, por ejemplo "EN ESPERA" como puedo agregarlo al ==1 ? "DISPONIBLE" : "AGOTADO";

Comment: @VictorHugo lo más idóneo es usar la información que hay en la tabla `estado`, haciendo un `JOIN`, pero como ya dije, dado que usas consultas genéricas, tienes que crear un método específico para `JOIN`, no puedes pasar ese tipo de consulta a `SelectAll` o `SelectOne` sin más, porque en esos métodos no se usa `JOIN`. Otra opción sería usar una array, pero no son soluciones idóneas, porque se supone que la tabla `estado` existe para usar los datos que hay en ella, así que lo más lógico sería empezar a implementar `JOIN`.